# WPF send event from App to User control

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

In my application, I use an event to check network status. In the MainWindow, I instantiate some user controls (for example, I have 3 child user controls), and in one of these child controls, I need to catch the event from the App to this specific user control.

In the App I use this to start:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    NetworkStatus.AvailabilityChanged +=
       new NetworkStatusChangedHandler(DoAvailabilityChanged);
    base.OnStartup(e);
}

static void DoAvailabilityChanged(
     object sender, NetworkStatusChangedArgs e)
        {
             //this method will send a notification
            //ReportAvailability();
        }
```

When I catch this event, I need to change the brushes in my StackPanel. After I have created the two brushes, how I can change them? I have seen some information about custom triggers. How can I use those in my StackPanel?

Comment: And what is your callback DoAvailabilityChanged, show us your code

Comment: DoAvailabilityChanged is to send a notification for the user controller. that i dont know how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Tunneling events.
In child viewmodel:

```
#region Events
public readonly static RoutedEvent NetworkStatusEvent =
       EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
           "NetworkStatusEvent",
           RoutingStrategy.Tunnel,
           typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
           typeof(NetworkStatusViewModel));
#endregion

   public void NetworkStatus_Changed(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Image = "home-scanner";
        IsAvailable = NetworkStatus.IsAvailable ? true : false;
        TextLegend = "sfsdfhf";
        //RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(NetworkStatusViewModel.GreetEvent, this));
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

In MainViewModel:

```
    private static NetworkStatusViewModel networkStatusViewModel = new NetworkStatusViewModel();

    public static NetworkStatusViewModel NetworkStatusViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return networkStatusViewModel;
        }
        //set {
        //    networkStatusViewModel = value;
        //}
    }
```

I hope this helps.